# Reactjs- comboDatePicker validation and restoring state

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have got 2 problems in my code:

1. I have a form which has common fields like name, user details. I am adding a date of birth field to the form. For that, using comboDatePicker. Problem is when I submit the form and come back to correct details on the form, all fields remain intact except Date of Birth. It goes back to default value.
2. What is simplest way to make this date of birth as mandatory.

Below is my code:

```
<Row>
    <Col sm={6} md={12}>
        <FormGroup>
           <Col md={3} mdOffset={1}>
              <ControlLabel>Date Of Birth</ControlLabel>
           </Col>
           <Col md={6}>
              <ComboDatePicker 
                     placeholder="Year,Month,Date"
                     id="dateOfBirth"
                     ref={e => refs.dateOfBirth = e}
                     onValueUpdated={preSaveFormState}                                                                                 
         attrsYear={{className:"form-control pull-left", style: {width: "auto"}}}
         attrsMonth={{className:"form-control pull-left", style: {width: "auto"}}}
         attrsDate={{className:"form-control pull-left", style: {width: "auto"}}}
              />
          </Col> 
        </FormGroup>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `date` prop for `ComboDatePicker` component.

```
<Row>
    <Col sm={6} md={12}>
        <FormGroup>
           <Col md={3} mdOffset={1}>
              <ControlLabel>Date Of Birth</ControlLabel>
           </Col>
           <Col md={6}>
              <ComboDatePicker 
                     placeholder="Year,Month,Date"
                     date={this.state.date} // you can set and read the date from state
                     id="dateOfBirth"
                     ref={e => refs.dateOfBirth = e}
                     onValueUpdated={preSaveFormState}                                                                                 
         attrsYear={{className:"form-control pull-left", style: {width: "auto"}}}
         attrsMonth={{className:"form-control pull-left", style: {width: "auto"}}}
         attrsDate={{className:"form-control pull-left", style: {width: "auto"}}}
              />
          </Col> 
        </FormGroup>
    </Col>
</Row>
```